# Why my code doesn't insert value also doesn't show any error?

Tags: php

Here is the form for taking input. When i press submit button page just reload and no error or success message. Also no data inserted in table. Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/user.php';
$obj_user = new User();
if (isset($_POST['reg-btn'])) {
    $message = $obj_user->save_user($_POST);
}
?>

<div class="col-md-8">
    <h3 class="text-info text-center"><u>এখানে নিবন্ধন করুন</u></h3>
    <?php if (isset($message)) {
        echo $message;
        unset($message);
    } ?>
    <hr/>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="first_name">নামের প্রথম অংশ</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="last_name">নামের শেষ অংশ</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email_address">ইমেইল ঠিকানা</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="email" name="email_address" id="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="user_name">ইউসারনেম</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" name="user_name" id="last_name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="password">পাসওয়ার্ড</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="address">ঠিকানা</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="address" id="address"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="city">শহর</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <input type="submit" name="reg_btn" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="নিবন্ধন সম্পন্ন">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the user class. I checked the connection, its ok.

```
<?php

require_once 'db_connect.php';

class User {

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        $obj_db = new Db_connect();
        $this->pdo = $obj_db->pdo;
    }

    public function save_user($data) {

        try {
            $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(first_name, last_name, email_address, user_name, password, address, city) VALUES(:first_name, :last_name, :email_address, :user_name, :password, :address, :city)";
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $data['first_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $data['last_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email_address', $data['email_address'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $data['user_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $data['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':address', $data['address'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':city', $data['city'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            $message = "আপনি সফলভাবে নিবন্ধন করেছেন";
            return $message;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `reg-btn`? Seems to not be set.. You also should hash passwords.

Comment: Your form `action` attribute is empty: do you handle the incoming post request at the same location as your html form?

Comment: @chirs85 you sir just save my life. Found my fault. i type '-' instead of '_' in button name. Many thanks.

Comment: @NishanSingha I've posted an answer, should give you some additional information as well for future debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if (isset($_POST['reg-btn'])) {` never fires because `$_POST['reg-btn']` is not set.

When in doubt about why something isn't firing trying taking out the conditional or giving it an `else` option to see which case it falls into. From there you can use `var_dump` to see what the values being sent are, etc.

So in this code you could have done:

```
if (isset($_POST['reg-btn'])) {
    $message = $obj_user->save_user($_POST);
} else {
     var_dump($_POST);
}
```

which would have shown you the name had the `_` instead of `-`. or

```
//if (isset($_POST['reg-btn'])) {
    $message = $obj_user->save_user($_POST);
//}
```

which would have allowed your form to process so you'd know `$_POST['reg-btn']` wasn't processing for some reason. The commenting out route is a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button name is `reg_btn` and you are checking `isset($_POST['reg-btn'])`

Replace this:

```
isset($_POST['reg-btn'])
```

with:

```
isset($_POST['reg_btn'])
```